# How to create scripts that create another scripts

Tags: command-line, server, bash, scripts, automation

I am writing an script that needs to generate another script that will be used to shutdown an appserver...

This is how my code looks like:

```
echo "STEP 8: CREATE STOP SCRIPT"
stopScriptContent="echo \"STOPING GLASSFISH PLEASE WAIT...\"\n
cd glassfish4/bin\n
chmod +x asadmin\n
./asadmin stop-domain\n
#In order to work it is required that the original folder of glassfish don't contain already any #project, otherwise, there will be a conflict\n"
${stopScriptContent} > stop.sh
chmod +x stop.sh
```

But it is not being created correctly, this is how the output stop.sh looks like:

```
"STOPING GLASSFISH PLEASE WAIT..."\n cd glassfish4/bin\n chmod +x asadmin\n ./asadmin stop-domain\n #In order to work it is required that the original folder of glassfish don't contain already any #project, otherwise, there will be a conflict\n
```

As you see, lots of things are wrong:

- there is no echo command
- is taking the \n literaly so there is no new line

My doubts are:

- What is the correct way of making an `.sh` script create another `.sh` script.
- What do you thing I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use echo with escaped characters like `\n` you should add the `-e` switch `echo -e " ... "`. However it may be easier to use `cat` with a [here document](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) instead

```
cat > stop.sh <<EOF
echo "STOPING GLASSFISH PLEASE WAIT..."
cd glassfish4/bin
chmod +x asadmin
./asadmin stop-domain
#In order to work it is required that the original folder of glassfish don't contain already any #project, otherwise, there will be a conflict
EOF
chmod +x stop.sh
```

Comment: I am unsure about this. Will I be able to have more stuff below?

Comment: @sfrj Yes, you will be. Just add your stuff before second `EOF`.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the \n's from your code and simply doing this worked for me.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "#!/bin/bash
      echo 'Hello World'" > b.sh
bash b.sh
```

Results in output;

```
Hello World
```